# Why SequenceEqual for List<T> returns false?

Tags: c#, list, comparison

Hi I have some problems with [sequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) when I have situation like this:

```
Sentence s1 = new Sentence { Text = "Hi", Order = 1 };
Sentence s2 = new Sentence { Text = "Hello", Order = 2 };
List<Sentence> list1 = new List<Sentence> { s1, s2 };
List<Sentence> list2 = new List<Sentence> { s1, s2 };
```

and this works fine

```
bool equal = list1.SequenceEqual(list2);
```

and returns `true`;

but when I have some method which returns `List<Sentence>`
for example:

```
public List<Sentence> Getall()
    {
        Sentence s1 = new Sentence { Text = "Hi", Order = 1 };
        Sentence s2 = new Sentence { Text = "Hello", Order = 2 };

        return new List<Sentence> { s1, s2 };
    }
```

and use it like this:

```
List<Sentence> list1 = Getall();
List<Sentence> list2 = Getall();
```

and then simply, check it

```
bool equal = list1.SequenceEqual(list2);
```

it returns 'false', please tell me why? and how to make it work?

Comment: Because in the second scenario they are different objects, i.e. their GetHash() methods return different values. In the first case they are exact same objects with two different *references*.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your problem is that one `new Sentence { Text = "Hi", Order = 1 }` is not equal to another `new Sentence { Text = "Hi", Order = 1 }`. Although the contents are the same, you have two separate objects, and unless you've designed your class otherwise they are not equal to each other unless they are literally the same objects (as in your first example).

Your `Sentence` class needs to override [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) and [`GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx), at the very least, at which point your `SequenceEquals` should work again.

Comment: This answer was close, but Patryk Ćwiek's answer which recommended the use of IEqualityComparer was the solution for me.

Answer (score 13):

As the [MSDN states here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx):

> Determines whether two sequences are equal by comparing the elements by **using the default equality comparer for their type.**

`Sentence` in your case is a reference type with default `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, which means it will be using referential equality for each element.

You can always use the [overload which accepts `IEqualityComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342073.aspx)

Comment: Good point about the possibility of using a comparer rather than defining behaviour in the class itself.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating two new instances of Sentence every time you call `Getall()`. When comparing the elements in the list, `SequenceEqual` will use the default equality comparer, which basically just check that they refer to the same object: they don't, so they are different.

What you can do is override the `Equal()` and `==` operators in Sequence to have equality check other properties (like Text and Order).

Alternatively you can write an `IEqualityComparer<Sequence>` and pass it to `SequenceEqual`