# Delete rows in datatable from another datatable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have two DataTables: `allRows` and `rowsToDelete`. I want to delete rows from `allRows` that `rowsToDelete` contains. Both tables have the same structure (same columns and their datatypes), but I can't know exact column names and even their quantity.

`object.Equals()` method recognizes rows from different tables as not equal so I can't use this approach.

From googling and reading StackOverflow I got an idea that probably it can be even done in one line, but I don't know how to build condition for this case:

```
allRows = allRows.AsEnumerable().Where(???).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works for any data structure, any columns' number and types. 
We present DataRows as arrays and compare each cell.

```
public static void DeleteCopies(DataTable allRows, DataTable rowsToDelete)
    {
        foreach (DataRow rowToDelete in rowsToDelete.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in allRows.Rows)
            {
                var rowToDeleteArray = rowToDelete.ItemArray;
                var rowArray = row.ItemArray;
                bool equalRows = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < rowArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!rowArray[i].Equals(rowToDeleteArray[i]))
                    {
                        equalRows = false;
                    }                            
                }
                if (equalRows)
                {
                    allRows.Rows.Remove(row);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the structure of your data but generally speaking you can do

```
var cleanedUp = allRows.Where(row => !rowsToDelete.Any(row2 => row2.Id == row.Id ));
```

Comment: That's the problem - structure can be different and there can be no "Id" column

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332635/c-sharp-compare-two-objects-of-unknown-types-including-reference-and-value-type

Answer (score 0):

If you don not have any primary key then check multiple columns that combinations(composite key)  provide you uniqueness on the behalf of which you can easily delete rows from all rows having similar data exist in rowsTodelete table.

Comment: If you read the question, the user does not know about the columns and their types

Comment: but i think user have rights to access database from there by select query he can access columns name easily.

Comment: I would say that's not the way of approaching the solution

Comment: but for my opinion under this circumstance this is the appropriate way to do this if you delete data from single table with out any identity column then first you have to now at least column names . If table exist then you easily use select statement to find column names isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

OR

First implement inner join among two tables on similar column for retrieving data that you want to delete and insert that into any temp table and delete this data from allrows table.

Hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your task has no solution, and you change the conditions,
first you write:

> Both tables have the same structure (same columns and their datatypes)

then you write:

> That's the problem - structure can be different and there can be no "Id" column

If you can even change the data, you can subtract both tables and investigate their structure, columns, etc. But you insist that you do not know them.

When you find out the structure, the task becomes elementary, smth like this(i use my structure from my own project):

```
var foo = DbContext
            .Set<Task>()
            .Select(x => new{x.Assignee, x.Availability})
            .ToList();

        var foo2 = DbContext
            .Set<Task2>()
            .Select(x => x)
            .ToList();

        var bar = foo2.Where(x => foo.Select(y => y.Assignee).Contains(x.Assignee) 
                                  && foo.Select(y => y.Availability).Contains(x.Availability));

        DbContext.RemoveRange(bar);
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

you can write more elegantly, but it's so obvious

Comment: I mean that it can be different from time to time but anyway it would be the same for both tables

Comment: I supposed you just tried to get some votes, not solve your problem. It's not real life application and your solution prove it:
first of all - SequenceEqual (if you do not redefine them) compare reference, not data(and obviously you get false even data is equal), even it same type
second, dude, really, you just take the table's structure and get it inline by linq, if you have access to DB, you can get the structure of the table.
ох уж эти братья славяне... какой пассаж.;)

Comment: It's real life application that extracts DataTables from user's .dbf files - that's why its' structure is unknown

Comment: @GlebGlazyrin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958098/why-sequenceequal-for-listt-returns-false

Comment: fixed this problem